# Почему при ромбовидном наследовании конструктор Pepega вызывается последним?

Tags: python, наследование

```
class Pepega:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
            print("this pepega()")

class Smart(Pepega):
    def __init__(self):
        print("__init__Smart")
        super().__init__()

class Monkey(Pepega):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Monkey()")
        super().__init__()

class SmartMonk(Monkey, Smart):
    def __init__(self):
        print("__init__SmartMonk")
        super().__init__()

smrtM = SmartMonk()
```

Comment: а вы не пробовали принты поставить после `super`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В питоне используется MRO - метод разрешение порядка при ромбовидном наследовании, можно почитать тут https://tirinox.ru/mro-python/